# Iterate over columns of existing dataframe to create a set of new dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I want to iterate over the columns of a dataframe to create a set of dataframes each consisting of the first "dates" column of the initial dataframe with the column at each iteration.

The main dataframe looks like this:
[Main Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMP0r.png)

I want to avoid going down the time consuming route of subsetting the main dataframe one by one using the column index (as in the example below), as there are 167 columns I want to create separate dataframes from alongside the date.

Is there a way to iterate using a for loop and referencing columns by name?

```
energy = returns.iloc[:,[0,2]]
health_care = returns.iloc[:,[0,3]]
...

etc
```

Comment: You should not create individual variables with the column names.  At worst, use a dictionary.  At best, I **suggest** you look at the pandas `transpose` operation, because I think that will do what you need to do.

Comment: This might be an XY problem but why are you trying to create a DataFrame of each column? What's the greater goal?

Comment: Reason for creating this is because not all the columns have data for each date (row). I want to apply a moving average on only those items that have a value. Dropna applied to whole rows is too crude as some columns have data and others do not

Answer (score 0):

For illustrative purposes, and assuming Dates is always the first column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Dates': pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01 01:04:16', periods=5), 'a':range(1,6), 'b':range(1,6), 'c':range(1,6)})
col_list = df.iloc[:, 1:].columns.tolist()
for c in col_list:
    dfnew = df.loc[:, ['Dates',c]]
    print(dfnew)

                Dates  a
0 2021-01-01 01:04:16  1
1 2021-01-02 01:04:16  2
2 2021-01-03 01:04:16  3
3 2021-01-04 01:04:16  4
4 2021-01-05 01:04:16  5
                Dates  b
0 2021-01-01 01:04:16  1
1 2021-01-02 01:04:16  2
2 2021-01-03 01:04:16  3
3 2021-01-04 01:04:16  4
4 2021-01-05 01:04:16  5
                Dates  c
0 2021-01-01 01:04:16  1
1 2021-01-02 01:04:16  2
2 2021-01-03 01:04:16  3
3 2021-01-04 01:04:16  4
4 2021-01-05 01:04:16  5
```

Comment: if  you want to create new dataframe names for each column, you can reference this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65924951/creating-loops-in-pandas/65930737#65930737